# background image somehow covers up all the controls adobe flash builder 4.6

Tags: flash-builder, skins

I created a skin using an image as background.

When my View imported the skin as skinClass, it covers up all the other controls.

How do i make all the controls display above the skin?

This is my Skin code called Background.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent")]
    </fx:Metadata>
    <s:Image source="assets/Sunflower.gif" smooth="true" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">

    </s:Image>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />

    </s:states>

</s:Skin>
```

This is the main view under default package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160"

                                   skinClass="BackgroundImage"
                                  >
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Add" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.AddView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="List" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.ListView"/>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Z index should be adjusted for the controls.
You can change your z-index like this:

```
parent.setChildIndex(childObject, i)
```

So for example if you want your controls to always be on front you need:

```
myControls.parent.setChildIndex(myControls, myControls.parent.numChildren -1)
```

Hope this helps you, even tho it's hard to answer it without any code...

Comment: I have included code above in the questions. Where do I put the setChildIndex methods you have mentioned above?